# Awk: replace column in one file with one column from another file

Tags: replace, awk

I have two files 
 File 1:

```
AAAAA01 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA02 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA03 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA04 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA05 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA06 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA07 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA08 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA09 T1  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA10 T2  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
AAAAA11 T2  0   0   0   0   C   C   G   G   G
```

File 2:

```
2   0
2   0
3   0
2   0
2   0
3   0
2   0
2   0
3   0
3   0
3   0
```

I have tried the following awk options.. but I only got the first row in column 6 replaced.

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$6=a[FNR]}1' File2.txt File1.txt > out1.txt

awk 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} NR == FNR {a[FNR] = $B; next} $A = a[FNR]' B=1 A=6 File2.txt File1.txt > out1.txt
```

How can I replace column 6 in File1 with column 1 in File2?

Comment: Actually both code worked after I use a perl script to make sure I have the newline characters correctly. Thanks to @karakfa and Murli. Both were great and helpful answers.

Comment: if you think our answers were usful. can you please accept either one of it!

Comment: Sure! Sorry I did not see that earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below piece of code -

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next}{$6=a[FNR]}1' File2.txt File1.txt > output.txt
```

this is giving me perfect output like below

```
AAAAA01 T1 0 0 0 2 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA02 T1 0 0 0 2 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA03 T1 0 0 0 3 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA04 T1 0 0 0 2 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA05 T1 0 0 0 2 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA06 T1 0 0 0 3 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA07 T1 0 0 0 2 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA08 T1 0 0 0 2 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA09 T1 0 0 0 3 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA10 T2 0 0 0 3 C C G G G<br/>                                                                                                                                               
AAAAA11 T2 0 0 0 3 C C G G G<br/>
```

when i tried on online emulator

Comment: Thank you Murli, I tried your code (actually that's the first try I had before moving on to other tips I googled), but I only got the first row in column 6 replaced, not the whole column.

Comment: @Molly_K I just tried this on one of online emulator since i don't have linux box running currently and its running perfectly, I have updated the answer with output.

Comment: Murli, thanks so much. I agree that works perfectly on the online emulator. I downloaded your file1 file2 and bash file and ran that on my terminal.. strangely, I got the same thing! Only the first row of the 6th column was replaced. It's quite annoying. I will test this again on a server.

Answer (score 2):

alternative solution

```
awk '{$6=$(NF-1); $(NF-1)=$NF=""}1' <(paste file1 file2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested the code and got a space separated file where the 6th column was not replaced and the 1st column was added to the file2 in an irregular way. e.g. added to file2 column 7 for the first row, and the rest of the info was added to the end of the file with both column 1 and 2 from file 1.

Comment: you may have an issue with line separators.

Comment: I think so too.. I just opened the file with vi editor... it turned out the file I had were not separated properly. Thank you so much for your time. I appreciate it.